# pod install: skip install on error - is there a command line option?

Tags: cocoapods

Is it possible to skip a Pod install should there be an error?

The reason being that I run `pod install` and it is currently exiting on one of the repos with:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository '<git repo>' not found
```

At the moment I'm just commenting out the line in the Podfile but I'd assume there's a command line option. I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command line option for this, as `Pod install` will just request `Podspec` of the specified pod listed in you `Podfile`.

If you comment or delete it, it will 'skip' the request & install step.

You can also use the `--verbose` option, to have a deeper understanding of what `cocoapods` is actually doing.